# Is there some way to provide multiple reducers as root ones using provideState()

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Current version of Angular and ngrx are 16.0.0.

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
      app: appReducer,
      anotherFeatureName: anotherFeatureReducer
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([
      AppEffects,
      AnotherEffects
    ]),
```

I started migration to standalone Angular app. So I need to get rid off StoreModule and EffectsModule from app.module.ts. But I can find the way to provide several reducers and relative effects using standalone API's.

Tried different ways to provide but no ones is working as expected. The state is undefined when app tries to read it.

Comment: Have you tried something like this:provideStore({ app: appReducer, anotherFeatureName: anotherFeatureReducer });?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yeah, the main problem was that I tried do this with provideState function but not a provideStore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First, make sure you have imported the necessary NgRx modules and your reducers and effects.**

```js
import { provideState } from '@ngrx/store';
import { provideEffects } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { appReducer } from './app.reducer';
import { anotherFeatureReducer } from './another-feature.reducer';
import { AppEffects } from './app.effects';
import { AnotherEffects } from './another.effects';
```

**2. In your app module, use the provideState() function to provide your root reducers**

```js
import { provideState } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //Remove StoreModule.forRoot()
    //Remove EffectsModule.forRoot()
    // Add provideState() to provide your root reducers
    provideState({
      app: appReducer,
      anotherFeatureName: anotherFeatureReducer,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**3. Similarly, use the provideEffects() function to provide your root effects**

```js
import { provideEffects } from '@ngrx/effects';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //Remove StoreModule.forRoot()
    //Remove EffectsModule.forRoot()
    // Add provideState() to provide your root reducers
    provideState({
      app: appReducer,
      anotherFeatureName: anotherFeatureReducer,
    }),

    // Add provideEffects() to provide your root effects
    provideEffects([AppEffects, AnotherEffects]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```